# Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't solve this problem where the console gives this error: `Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function`. This is the code it points to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".linky").click(function(){
        var t = $(this); //<-ERROR POINTS HERE
        var y = $("#0"+t.attr("id")).offset().top;
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: y},500);
    });
});
</script>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you including jQuery library? If the answer is yes, is it loaded correctly (check console)? Is this code placed after jQuery loading line?

Comment: Whenever you get this error just check if you have included jquery library or not. Secondally it may be due to conflicts having more than one jquery libraries on the same page..

Comment: FOR SURE YOU HAVE N'T INCLUDED JQUERY FILE

Comment: If you are including the JQuery Library then you may want to post more of your code, like the HTML etc.

Comment: Is the jQuery script from a (re)source that is available? Open the console, do you have any loading resource error? like 404 or ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the jquery script

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's already included

Comment: try adding this, <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: check the network tab to ensure jquery is actually loading, you should see a file retrieved for jquery.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe `jQuery.noConflict();` it's being used somewhere inside your site. Try with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function( $ ) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".linky").click(function(){
      var t = $(this); //<-ERROR POINTS HERE
      var y = $("#0"+t.attr("id")).offset().top;
      $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: y},500);
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```