# DataTables not initializing due to "$ is not a function"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, datatables

I want to initialize my DataTables, I already downloaded it, call it, and everything seems okay, but when I call the JQuery function to run the datatables it gives me this weird error.

> TypeError: $ is not a function

But my code seems okay:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
$('#table_id').DataTable();
} );
```

THis is my HTML:

```
<table id="table_id" class="display">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th>Column 2</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
        <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
        <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

What can this be?

Script order:

> ```
> <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets2/js/vendor/jquery-2.1.4.min.js');?>"></script>
>     <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/datatables.min.js');?>"></script>
>
>     <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/Backoffice_JS.js');?>"></script>
> ```

Comment: Did you  import jQuery in the page (before any code that requires it)?

Comment: @Pointy yeah, this is how it looks.

Comment: Well check the Network tab in your browser developer tools to verify that jQuery is actually loading from the path your code builds.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/30630839/5468463

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery - $ is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2194992/608639) and [Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30630839/608639)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### TypeError: $ is not a function

Means that the javascript is not recognizing jquery.

To solve this you need to include jquery CDN before your script code.
So it should be like this :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
   $(document).ready( function () {
      $('#table_id').DataTable();
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can’t put comment because i ´m novice. 
So, your problem isn’t datatable, but jQuery. As said in comment, you must import jquery before using jQuery syntax. Use jquery with cdn or import library in your project.

Comment: I pushed it up to the top of the page but now I got an error telling me that "TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function"

Comment: Have you import correctly datatable js and css files ?

Comment: Thanks everyone, I has miss imported certain files!

Comment: Happy for you, if your problem is resolved, close your question and mark the response as resolved.